# How to solve 404 for static files with Django and Nginx?

Tags: server, nginx, django

I setup a Trusty VM with Django + Nginx ([other stuffs](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/) too).

The server is working, I get the ["Welcome to Django"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CDHC.png) page. But when I enter to `servername/admin` it [loads the HTML page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UxmS.png) but fails to load the static content.

And [the admin page](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7595349/) have this links to static content:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/login.css" />
```

Both of the CSS files give me 404, as the Nginx log shows:

```
192.168.56.1 - - [05/Jun/2014:12:04:09 -0300] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"
192.168.56.1 - - [05/Jun/2014:12:04:09 -0300] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 833 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"
192.168.56.1 - - [05/Jun/2014:12:04:10 -0300] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 142 "http://ubuntu-server/admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"
192.168.56.1 - - [05/Jun/2014:12:04:10 -0300] "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 404 142 "http://ubuntu-server/admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"
```

I think that the error is on my [nginx.conf](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7595386/) file, but no idea how to solve it. This is the site tree:

[image: screenshoot]

Major files: [`urls.py`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7639193/), [`settings.py`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7639212/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is most likely a problem of configuration in django or Nginx

There are two things you want to check:

1. Are your staticfiles configured correctly in settings.py? For the basic django page, these settings are not necessary, but for your static files, you need to configure static files. That is not necessary for production use, because there the webserver serves the static files. Are they collected? Once configured you might have to run `python manage.py collectstatic`.

   For instance,

   ```
   #settings.py
   INSTALLED_APPS += [django.contrib.staticfiles,]
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   STATIC_ROOT = '/your_path/.../static/'

   # This collects all files in /static/ directories and puts them in the static ROOT folder.
   python manage.py collectstatic
   ```
2. Django does not serve static files by itself (unless you set `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py`), thus you will have to add a configuration in engine x to make it serve the static files. You might have to restart nginx and/or add `autoindex on;` to your config for /static/ in nginx.conf.

See [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/).

In development, you might also have to add the `/static/` url to your urls.py (in development) and not just the settings.

Comment: I tried with the three methods, none worked. I made modification to `nginx.conf` and then restart the service, but still. Tried also adding the following line into `urls.py` but no luck.. `url(r'^static/', include(admin.site.urls)),`

Comment: Can you post your django settings, your main urls.py and the output of `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: After reading the output of that command, I noted that I wrote a wrong path. Now it worked! Without `autoindex` the directory. What I do not understand is, should I do this on production?

Comment: Lucio, you should indeed collect static files on production. Or at least, I do it on production as part of the deployment process (using fabric) so as to make sure I really have *all* the static files (also those in a new version of an old app, for instance).

Comment: So you mean i have to execute this command manually everytime i upload a new static file?

Comment: @Cody yes, it should be part of your deployment script

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem and a slight change in the nginx configuration solved it for me.

This was my nginx config for serving static files:

```
location /static/ {
    root /home/muqube/muqube_website/muqube/muqube_static_root/;
}
```

The solution was to replace `root` with `alias`, like so:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/muqube/muqube_website/muqube/muqube_static_root/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing  you have the wrong file paths. According to what the server is saying the admin and static folders are in the same path.

Also on Linux / is  the root path. Your files aren't in the root directory.

Again I am just guessing, hope that this helps!

Comment: What files and why should be in the root directory? I don't see where the server is saying that `admin` and `static` folders are in the same path.